# Updating column values in a Pandas Dataframe the correct way

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I am working on the common starter competition in [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/leaderboard#score) , and realised adding Age to the classifier helps. The problem is, it has **NaN** values for the Age column, I don't want to fill all NaNs on the whole df, just the Age column. I apply the solution below, (by getting a median), then targeting the rows and updating like this `_train['Age'] = X_train['Age'].fillna(X_train_median)` for example.

I know this is not good practice, it works but I get the following error

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Is it possible to update a specific column for all values matching a certain criteria in a df in a better way?  Example code below.

```
# IMPORT DATA 
train_data = pd.read_csv("data/train.csv")
test_data = pd.read_csv("data/test.csv")

# ASSIGN TO VAR
X_test = test_data
X = train_data
y = train_data["Survived"]

# SPLIT 
X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

# SELECTED FEATURES 
features = ["Pclass", "Sex", "SibSp", "Parch", "Embarked", "Age"]


# REMOVE NA's BY POPULATING WITH MEDIAN VAL
X_train_median = X_train['Age'].median()
X_val_median = X_val['Age'].median()
X_test_median = X_test['Age'].median()

X_train['Age'] = X_train['Age'].fillna(X_train_median)
X_val['Age'] = X_val['Age'].fillna(X_val_median)
X_test['Age'] = X_test['Age'].fillna(X_test_median)


# ONE HOT FOR CATAGORICAL VALS
X_train = pd.get_dummies(X_train[features])
X_val = pd.get_dummies(X_val[features])
X_test = pd.get_dummies(X_test[features])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
X_train['Age'] = X_train.loc[:, 'Age'].fillna(X_train_median)
X_val['Age'] = X_val.loc[:, 'Age'].fillna(X_val_median)
X_test['Age'] = X_test.loc[:, 'Age'].fillna(X_test_median)
```

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Comment: Thanks @asymmetryFan that did the job! I see the: in the first field of loc[] means all the rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can try, with X being some DataFrame:

```py
X = X.assign(Age = X['Age'].fillna(value=X_median))
```